# preferences - add value to end list pref android

Tags: android, preferences

I am trying to add an item to a list pref,using this:

```
void setupValues(ListPreference pref) {
    CharSequence[] entries= pref.getEntries();
    entries[entries.length]="l";
    pref.setEntries(entries);
}
```

But this is not working, although I am able to create a new CharSequence and set as EntryValues, like this:

```
void setupValues(ListPreference pref) {
    CharSequence[] entries= {"d","e"};
    pref.setEntries(entries);
}
```

So is there any solution?

Comment: Try entries[entries.length-1]="l";

Comment: you dont understand, I dont want to edit,I want to add entries.

Comment: Create bigger CharSequence array, copy old values, add new ones and it's done. :)

Comment: an example would be nice........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code. I didn't implemented but may solve your proflem.

```
CharSequence[] entries = new String[pref.getEntries().length + 1];

int i = 0;
for (CharSequence cs : pref.getEntries()) {
    entries[i] = cs;
    i++;
}

entries[entries.length] = "l";
pref.setEntries(entries);
```